# Notepad++ Codefolding - Everything but the header is under body tag?

Tags: html, notepad++, footer, code-folding

basically, under the `<html>` tag  i have `<head>`, `<body>`, and `<footer>`. under those i have the divs and whatever. using the codefolding, i can have just `<html>`, and everything else hide.

if i expand that, i get the ability to expand `<head>`, and `<body>`. no ability to expand footer. if you expand body, then you get the ability to expand footer. another thing is, the html closing tag is also hidden under the `<body>` tag.

its not a big issue, but it's really annoying because i like to have it all organized.

help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question is really hard to understand. You'd need to try to use proper English and specify the pproblem more clearly.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. I edited your post because you didn't use proper formatting so all the html tags were invisible. It's usually a good idea to, after you post, verify that it looks the way it's supposed to and fix any formatting/syntax errors if it looks off.

Comment: In addition, your status suggests you have not yet taken the [Welcome to Stack Overflow! Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like you have improper matched tags, or perhaps typos. Did you try a new document that is just

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
  <footer></footer>
</html>
```

to see if that folds correctly? If it does, it is quite likely there are simply problems in how your tags are ordered or written.

On an HTML5 note, `<footer>` goes inside the `<body>` element, not outside of it. It's a normal content tag, so goes inside the main document body.

Comment: Yea I'm just kind of dumb. I had a div inside of another div, so I closed the inner div, and forgot to close the outer one... This made everything become part of the div, not individual sections.